Workflow seems to not catch the if conditions
What I want to do is send a notification to my Slack channel of the workflow outcomes whether or not it's successful.
I also wanted the Slack messages displays different colors depending on the result of the workflow.
This used to work on my previous versions of my workflow but after I bumped up some of the package versions it seems to ignore the if: ${{ github.workflow == 'Unittest' }} conditions.
enter image description here
This is my workflow:
name: Unittest

on:
  workflow_call:
  push:

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Configure aws credential
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v4

      - name: Checkout firebase admin sdk
        run:

      - name: Set up MySQL
        run:
        env:
          DB_DATABASE:
          DB_LEGACY: 
          DB_USER: 
          DB_PASSWORD:

      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v5
        with:
          python-version: "3.11.3"

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install pipenv --user
          pipenv run pipenv requirements --dev > requirements.txt
          pip install flake8 pytest
          if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi

      - name: Lint with flake8
        run: |
          # stop the build if there are Python syntax errors or undefined names
          flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics
          # exit-zero treats all errors as warnings. The GitHub editor is 127 chars wide
          flake8 . --count --exit-zero --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=127 --statistics

      - name: Test with pytest
        run: |
          pytest --html=report.html --self-contained-html

        env:

      - name: Notification
        if: ${{ github.workflow == 'Unittest' }}
        uses: 8398a7/action-slack@v3
        with:
          status: custom
          fields: workflow,job,commit,repo,ref,author,took
          custom_payload: |
            {
              attachments: [{
                color: '${{ job.status }}' === 'success' ? 'good' : '${{ job.status }}' === 'failure' ? 'danger' : 'warning',
                text: `${process.env.AS_WORKFLOW}\n${process.env.AS_JOB} (${process.env.AS_COMMIT}) of ${process.env.AS_REPO}@${process.env.AS_REF} by ${process.env.AS_AUTHOR} ${{ job.status }} in ${process.env.AS_TOOK}`,
              }]
            }
        env:
          SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL: ${{ secrets.SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL }}

      - name: Upload Report
        if: ${{ github.workflow == 'Unittest' }}
        uses: MeilCli/slack-upload-file@v4
        with:
          slack_token: ${{ secrets.ACTION_BOT_TOKEN }}
          channel_id: C0278JD7H7B
          file_path: "report.html"
          initial_comment: "Unittest Report : ${{ github.repository }}"
     

I tried changing the if condition to always() and worked. However I only want this Notification step to be executed when the Unittest named workflow runs because this workflow is called in different workflows and don't want the Notification step to be executed elsewhere.
I also echoed github.workflow and printed out the exact str value that I wanted
I tried removing the brackets as so if: github.workflow == 'Unittest' and also only added the brackets at github.workflow variable as so if: ${{ github.workflow }} == 'Unittest' but doesn't seem to do the trick.
What am I missing?

By default, all the subsequent workflow job steps are skipped if any previous steps fail. This is exactly the case from your image. After bumping the deppendecies some of the tests started to fail so the subsequent steps are skipped so you have a false impression

after I bumped up some of the package versions it seems to ignore the if: ${{ github.workflow == 'Unittest' }} conditions

The condition is not ignored but the entire step is skipped (regardless the evaluation result of the condition).
To execute the Notification step regardless of the results of the previous steps we need to add an if statement with always() expression to the step. You have already tried that

I tried changing the if condition to always() and worked.

Now, we can combine always() with your original expression to get the expected outcome:
- name: Notification
  if: always() && github.workflow == 'Unittest'
  [...]

